# When I click on the button, the button id should be returned to me. JSON file

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a dictionary in which there is a question and its id. I loop through all the questions and display them as buttons, then when I click on the button I should return the id of this question, how to do this ??

```
def start(message):
    r = requests.get("http://x.x.x.x/api/tests/list/getusertestlist", headers=headers)# I get JSON file
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    for i in dp.values(r.json(), "/tests/*/value"):# value it's questions.
        itembtn = types.KeyboardButton(i)
        markup.add(itembtn)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Get test",reply_markup=markup)

Structure JSON file.
{'tests': [{'description': 'Choose your preferred answer from the suggested ones.', 'id': 85, 'value': 'test 1'}, {'description': 'Choose your preferred answer from the suggested ones.', 'id': 88, 'value': 'test 1'}]}
```

In the end I should get a keyboard with 2 buttons test 1 and test 2, when I click on test 1 I should get its ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got lost with your snippet. Variables like "dp" or "types" weren't declared. Also I don't have a json test file on internet at hand so I declared it in the same file (using the example you give).

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
import json

jsonfile='{"tests": [{"description": "Choose your preferred answer from the suggested ones.", "id": 85, "value": "test 1"}, {"description": "Choose your preferred answer from the suggested ones.", "id": 88, "value": "test 1"}]}'

def start(update, context):
    keybrd = []
    jsondic=json.loads(jsonfile)
    for item in jsondic['tests']:
        keybrd.append([InlineKeyboardButton(item['value'], callback_data=item['id'])])
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keybrd)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,text="Get test",reply_markup=markup)

def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text(text="Selected option: {}".format(query.data))

def main():
    updater = Updater(tgtoken, use_context=True)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
```

That's the idea, you should probably need to rearrange the buttons. You also need to finish the main function with start_polling() and declare the logger but all those details can be found in the inlinekeyboard example at the github of this wrapper.